# how do i style a specific line in a block

Tags: css

First time css coder.

Here is a snippet

```
`<main>
        <div class="body_introduction">
            <h2>Ways to contact us.</h2>
            
            <ul>
                <li>Email us at: <a style="text-decoration: none" 
                    href = "mailto:company.com">company</a></li>
                <li>Call us at:<a style="text-decoration: none" 
                    href="tel:1(555)-555-555.">1(555)-555-5555</li>
                <li>You could always send a text: 
                    <a style="text-decoration: none" href="tel:1(555)-555-5555.">1(555)-555-5555</a>
                <li>You could always stop by our office! We are located at 
                    <a href="http://maps.google.com/?q=address">
                    address</a>
                    
            </ul>
        </div>

    </main>`
```

how would i be able to style the `<li>` a specific color, while assigning the `<a>` another color?

I still do not understand how one manages to color different sections of code with different colors while using the `<p>` allover the page.

i tried to use

`li.a` but that did not work as expected.

Comment: Did you mean `li > a` ?

Comment: Could you make your HTML valid? There are unclosed elements which the validator is objecting to).

Answer (score 0):

```css
.body_introduction ul li{
color: red
}

.body_introduction ul li a{
color: green;
}
```

```html
<main>
        <div class="body_introduction">
            <h2>Ways to contact us.</h2>
            
            <ul>
                <li>Email us at: <a style="text-decoration: none" 
                    href = "mailto:company.com">company</a></li>
                <li>Call us at:<a style="text-decoration: none" 
                    href="tel:1(555)-555-555.">1(555)-555-5555</li>
                <li>You could always send a text: 
                    <a style="text-decoration: none" href="tel:1(555)-555-5555.">1(555)-555-5555</a>
                <li>You could always stop by our office! We are located at 
                    <a href="http://maps.google.com/?q=address">
                    address</a>
                    
            </ul>
        </div>

    </main>
```

Are you searching for something like this?